# Is there a definitive source that itemizes all the new stuff in a version of the .NET framework?

Tags: c#

I just noticed that `PropertyInfo.GetValue(object)` exists.  I'm used to adding that extra null value for the indexer.

So I brought up the F1 help on the method I found the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.GetValue%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1%29;k%28DevLang-csharp%29&rd=true) and switching to versions previous to 4.5 confirmed it is new.

Asking myself how I might have known this without stumbling upon it, I scanned these [what's new notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#core) and didn't find anything.

Is there a definitive source that itemizes all the new stuff in a version of the .NET framework?

Comment: I think you already found the best resource, but I would be interested to know if there is anything else.

Comment: No, that kind of documentation would quickly bore anyone to tears.  It is already highly discoverable through IntelliSense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are really going to get bored, these links might be interesting:

[New Types and Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn527271%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (the PropertyInfo.GetValue(object) was not mentioned),

[Obsolete Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419162%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Obsolete members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh419161%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Obsolete summary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee461502%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Also (just by the way) almost the same for .NET 4:

[.NET 4 new Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff641764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[.NET 4 new types and members Part 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff652744%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[.NET 4 new types and members Part 2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff658359%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)